# Dropdown menu behind content in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a problem and that is that the dropdown menu is seen behind the content only on "WooCommerce" pages as "Store" or "Checkout", since it looks fine on the static pages of the site. If anyone can give me more ideas as to what may be causing the problem, I would appreciate it.

This is what the problem looks like:

[image]

I already tried modifying the "overflow" in the section settings, and also setting higher z-indexes, but nothing works.

[DevTools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z23Ml.jpg)

[DevTools 2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMlP.jpg)

The site is https://pokelan.com and the specific page with the issue is https://pokelan.com/tienda/ (currently modified the position of the dropdown to allow the users see it)

Comment: Try to set/increase the [CSS `z-index` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php) for the related menu items (or the menu itself).

Comment: z-index is context specific so you may have to increase it on the parent instead of the menu, so it gets higher positioning over the content container.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: try increasing z-index with !important. Can you show image of devtools?

Comment: @Squirrl the page URL is https://pokelan.com, and the issue is in the URL https://pokelan.com/tienda/

For the moment I modified the position of the dropdown menu so that it is visible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition to the z-index did you try adding a position, such as `position:relative` or `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @Squirrl Yes, i just tried with the position. It affects all the structure of the header and menu, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: When I visit the site I don't see it being hidden even when I adjust the css in the tools.  Is this still happening?  Can you post some css and html?